# ssh/known_hosts: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, gitlab

So I'm setting up GitLab and I've encountered a problem along the way. Namely, https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/gitlab_com/index.html#ssh-host-keys-fingerprints this link calls for adding entries to `known_hosts`. The problem is, however, that when I'm trying to run a command like `/.ssh$ .ssh/known_hosts gitlab.com ssh-ed25519 ...` I get this error.

I've just set up this ssh stuff from scratch.

Comment: What command are you running? `.ssh/known_hosts` is a file to edit, not a command to run.

Comment: ehm apparently I don't even have that file in the first place. Is there a way to create it?

Comment: Use any text editor. `ssh` uses it if it's found. If the file isn't found, or the host you are connecting to isn't found in the file, `ssh` will add the file after confirming you want to connect.

Comment: ok VonC below helped with establishing this file, but how do I edit it?

Comment: @Askar Why do you want to edit it? Its content will be auto-generated by `ssh`. But if you want to, any text editor will do.

Comment: @VonC Ideally, you should verify the host key before connecting. While you could try to connect, get the host key, verify it, then answer "yes", you might also verify the host key ahead of time, add it manually to `know_hosts`, then try to connect.

Comment: @chepner I agree. I have edited the answer to reference a best practice and illustrate how you get the fingerprint and compare it to an official source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> apparently I don't even have that file in the first place. Is there a way to create it?

It will be created for you on your first `ssh` call

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.com
```

That iwll trigger a message like:

```sh
The authenticity of host '111.222.333.444 (111.222.333.444)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is f1:cf:58:ae:71:0b:c8:04:6f:34:a6:b2:e4:1e:0c:8b.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Answering yes will create the `~/.ssh/known_hosts`

---

As [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/c) says in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68332819/ssh-known-hosts-no-such-file-or-directory?noredirect=1#comment120773920_68332819), you should get the server actual fingerprint ahead of times, before answering 'yes', and comparing that fingerprint to what is added to the `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

See for instance "[Securely add a host (e.g. GitHub) to the SSH known_hosts file](https://serverfault.com/a/1059127/783)".

For instance: `github.com` does [give its server fingerprints](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints): compare it with  `ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com | ssh-keygen -lf -`.

```sh
C:\Users\vonc\git>ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com | ssh-keygen -lf -
# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-4cec2db4
2048 SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8 github.com (RSA)
```

If it matches, then add it to your `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.